# Get data from firebase into UITableViewController - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from my Firebase database into my `UITableViewController`.

The meaning of the `UITableViewController` is to display who has liked the post you are visiting.

When someone likes a post, their `userID` is being placed in the post under the category `likesForPost` - as you can see here:

[image]

As you can see 1 person has already liked this post (the black box is a `userID`).

The problem is that I do not get any data displayed on my cell. I am trying to display the `userID` on my cell but nothing shows. I do however get the number of cells equal to the number of people that has liked the post.

I should explain the that `viaSegue` is getting a key from a `prepareForSegue` and yes it is displaying the correct key, so that is not the problem :-)

Here is my `UITableViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FirebaseStorage

class viewLikesTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var viaSegue = "Nothing"
    var updates = [LikeSweet]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
        self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView

        print(viaSegue)

        startObersvingDB()
    }

    func startObersvingDB() {
            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").child(self.viaSegue).child("likesForPost").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
                    // Get user value
                var newUpdates = [LikeSweet]()

                for update in snapshot.children {
                    let updateObject = LikeSweet(snapshot: update as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                    newUpdates.append(updateObject)

                }

                self.updates = newUpdates
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }) { (error: NSError) in
                print(error.description)
            }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return updates.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        let update = updates[indexPath.row]

        let allDataSend = update.userID
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showProfile", sender: allDataSend)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:viewLikesTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! viewLikesTableViewCell

            let update = updates[indexPath.row]

            cell.nameLabel.text = update.userID
        return cell
    }
}
```

You might also want the `LikeSweet` code:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import UIKit

struct LikeSweet {
    let key: String!
    let userID: String!
    let itemRef: FIRDatabaseReference?
    let path : String!

    init (userID: String, key: String = "") {
        self.key = key
        self.userID = userID
        self.itemRef = nil
        // self.path = dataPath
        self.path = ""
    }

    init (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        key = snapshot.key
        itemRef = snapshot.ref
        path  = key
        if let theFeedContent = snapshot.value!["userID"] as? String {
            userID = theFeedContent
        } else {
            userID = ""
        }
    }

    func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
        return ["userID":userID]
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you receive something in snapshot.children?
Did you receive the data in self.updates array?

Comment: @AndrewVeresov I added a `print` to see what is in `updateObject` and I got this: `LikeSweet(key: "userID", userID: "", itemRef: ****link***, path: "userID")`

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the `LikeSweet`? When I use this code: `if let theFeedContent = snapshot.value!["userID"] as? String {
            userID = theFeedContent
        } else {
            userID = "Got nothing"
        }`

The cell label is writting "Got nothing".. I just do not know how to make it get the snapshot?

Comment: so in cellForRow you try to set cell.nameLabel.text = update.userID, but in ypur response you recived empty string in userID field.

Comment: Check the snapshot.children did you recived the empty userid?

Comment: @AndrewVeresov I do not know how to check the snapshot.children? When I use `print(snapshot.children)` I get a weird code

Comment: use the :  (for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as [FDataSnapshot]) {
       println(rest.value)     
    }

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as calling your

```
self.updates = newUpdates
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

on the main queue. You can't update the UI on a non-main thread.

Try and do this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.updates = newUpdates
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```